# Unable to print vbscript output on web page and unable to save vbscript output in text file

Tags: html, xml, vbscript

Hi

I want to print vbscript output to a webpage and save it in notepad using vbscript.

This is my html code with vbscript.

```
<html>
<body>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">
    Const XMLDataFile = "D:\Automation\imp\p.xml"
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.Async = False
xmlDoc.Load(XMLDataFile)
    xmlDoc.validateOnParse = True  
    If xmlDoc.Load(XMLDataFile) Then 
        Document.write("SUCCESS loading XML File")  
    Else  
        Document.write("ERROR loading XML File")  
    End If
    counter=0  
    Set root = xmlDoc.documentElement
    Set items = root.childNodes
    for each item in items
      myPNAME = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("PNAME").item(counter).text
      myPTYP = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("PTYP").item(counter).text
      myPGROUP = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("PGROUP").item(counter).text
      If (Left(myPNAME, 1) = "I") Then
              IsValid = True
        If (Left(myPTYP, 1) <> "I") Then
             IsValid = False
        End If
        If (Left(myPGROUP, 1) <> "I" )Then
             IsValid = False
        End If
        If IsValid = False Then
            Document.write(myPNAME & " is not valid.")
        End If
        IsValid = True
      End If
      If (Left(myPNAME, 1) = "V") Then
            IsValid = True
            If (Left(myPTYP, 1) <> "V") Then
                IsValid = False
            End If
            If (Left(myPGROUP, 1) <> "V" )Then
                IsValid = False
            End If
            If IsValid = False Then
                Document.write(myPNAME & " is not valid.")
            End If
            IsValid = True
       End If
       If (Left(myPNAME,1) = "E") Then
      If (Left(myPNAME,5)="E_MSG")Then
    IsValid=false
      End if
          IsValid = True
          If (Left(myPTYP, 1) <> "E") Then
             IsValid = False
          End If
          If (Left(myPGROUP, 1) <> "E" )Then
              IsValid = False
          End If
          If IsValid = False Then
                Document.write(myPNAME & " is not valid.")
          End If
          IsValid = True
       End If
       If (Left(myPNAME,2) = "IT") Then
          IsValid = True
            If (Left(myPTYP, 1) <> "I") Then
              IsValid = False
            End If
            If (Left(myPGROUP, 1) <> "I" )Then
               IsValid = False
            End If
            If IsValid = False Then
                 Document.write(myPNAME & " is not valid.")
            End If
            IsValid = True
        End If
        If (Left(myPNAME,2) = "VT") Then
          IsValid = True
            If (Left(myPTYP, 1) <> "V") Then
              IsValid = False
        End If
        If (Left(myPGROUP, 1) <> "V" )Then
              IsValid = False
        End If
        If IsValid = False Then
              Document.write(myPNAME & " is not valid.")
        End If
        IsValid = True
      End If
      If (Left(myPNAME,1) = "IS") Then
          IsValid = True
         If (Left(myPTYP, 1) <> "I") Then
             IsValid = False
         End If
         If (Left(myPGROUP, 1) <> "I" )Then
            IsValid = False
         End If
        If IsValid = False Then
         Document.write(myPNAME & " is not valid.")
        End If
        IsValid = True
      End If
  If (Left(myPNAME,2) = "VS") Then
      IsValid = True
         If (Left(myPTYP, 1) <> "V") Then
            IsValid = False
         End If
         If (Left(myPGROUP, 1) <> "V" )Then
            IsValid = False
         End If
         If IsValid = False Then
             Document.write(myPNAME & " is not valid.")
         End If
         IsValid = True
      End If
counter=counter+1
   next
  </SCRIPT>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Please provide solution for how to display the vbscript output on a webpage and how to save the output to notepad.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this your code? Cause it looks like you're already using `Document.Write()`, which is how you output to the page. For saving to a text file, check out the `FileSystemObject` and its `CreateTextFile` method.

Comment: Yes this is my code. When I replace Document.write() method with MsgBox() in vbscript output is displayed as per my expection but when i'm trying to same output on webpage using Document.write() then I am not able to display output. I'm using Internet explorer as my browser.

Comment: Vbscript uses response.write not document.write

Answer (score 0):

Good day

Firstly are you testing this in Internet Explorer? You should.

Secondly, you should try something a little more simpler, like opening a text file and just printing out the output.

Here is sample code, I added the TYPE (to the script definition) and it now outputs:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE>A Simple First Page</TITLE>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript" type="text/VBScript">
<!--

document.Write("Please don't click me")

Sub Button1_OnClick
   MsgBox "Mirabile visu."
   document.Write("<b>Hello World</b>")
End Sub
-->
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<H3>A Simple First Page</H3><HR>
<FORM><INPUT NAME="Button1" TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="Click Here"></FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

If you looking for information on how to save output to a textfile, check out the VBScript Guide.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx7b3k7y(v=vs.84).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx7b3k7y%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

Writing to text file would look something like this, but be advised for what you trying to do you may run into security issues (impersonation may be needed).

```
Const FOR_READING = 1
Const FOR_WRITING = 2

strFileName = "C:\scripts\test.txt"
strNewContent  = "sample string content"

Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTS = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFileName,FOR_READING)
strContents = objTS.ReadAll
objTS.Close
Set objTS = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFileName,FOR_WRITING)
objTS.WriteLine strNewContent
objTS.Write strContents
```

Comment: When I replace Document.write() method with MsgBox() in vbscript output is displayed as per my expection but when i'm trying to same output on webpage using Document.write() then I am not able to display output. I'm using Internet explorer as my browser.